# Send Encryption Password To LDAP in Java

Tags: java, encryption, ldap

I have a problem and I have no idea how to solve it.

I load an encrypted password (SSHA) from a text file and I need add a user with this password from the source code in Java.

Example from file:
e1NTSEF9Ukd6ZEZyanZBZlJGMGs3eGFDOGZxQ3U3QlozcUZXRGJoeWIyS0E9PQ==

Real password: 123

Example code not work as I want:

```
String encryptedPSWD = "e1NTSEF9Ukd6ZEZyanZBZlJGMGs3eGFDOGZxQ3U3QlozcUZXRGJoeWIyS0E9PQ==";
attributes.add(new BasicAttribute("userPassword","{SSHA}"+encryptedPSWD);
```

It not work, because we can send only real value password?
And is the problem that this is one-sided encryption and LDAP will also not be able to decrypt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error number and text from the LDAP server would be instructive; but, in a general case, there are two things that stand out:

(1) Assuming the user already has a password, you are *modifying* an existing attribute, not adding an attribute. If you attempt to add a value to a single valued attribute that's already got a value, or if you attempt to add a value to a multi-value attribute that is already present, you would get ldap error 20. To *modify* an existing attribute would look something like this:

```
LDAPModificationSet attributes = new LDAPModificationSet();
LDAPAttribute attrUserPassword = new LDAPAttribute("userPassword", "{SSHA}"+encryptedPSWD);
attributes.add(LDAPModification.REPLACE, attrUserPassword);
```

(2) Some directories do not allow using "pre-encoded" passwords as a default. This is because password policies cannot be applied to an unknown password (i.e. how do I know this password is at least eight characters, contains a special character, and does not contain a dictionary word?). The Oracle Unified Directory servers that I manage return error 53 in this case, along with text saying "Pre-encoded passwords are not allowed for the password attribute userPassword.", but other directory servers may return use a different code (53 is a pretty generic code that just means something in the server config prevented the action from being completed). How to sort it depends on the LDAP server -- mine have a allow-pre-encoded-passwords Boolean within the password policy. I generally set it to "true", bulk import users, then return the setting to 'false' to prevent app developers from circumventing our password policies.